# Jetpack Compose view doesn't observes state updates

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I have a state class

```
object SomeState {
 data class State(
   val mainPhotos: List<S3Photo>? = emptyList(),
 )
}
```

VM load data via init and updates state

```
class SomeViewModel() {
    var viewState by mutableStateOf(SomeState.State())
        private set
    init {
     val photos = someSource.load()
     viewState = viewState.cope(mainPhotos = photos)
    }
}
```

Composable takes data from state

```
@Composable
fun SomeViewFun(
   state = SomeState.State
) {
   HorizontalPager(
      count = state .mainPhotos?.size ?: 0,
  ) {
    //view items
   }
}
```

The problem is that `count` in `HorizontalPager` always == 0, but in logcat and debugger i see that `list.size() == 57`
I have a lot of screen with arch like this and they works normaly. But on this screen view state doesn't updates and i can't understand why.

**UPDATE**

VM passes to Composable like this

```
@Composable
fun SomeDistanation() {
   val viewModel: SomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
   SomeViewFun(
     state = viewModel.state
   )
}
```

Also Composable take `Flow<ViewEffect>` and etc, but in this question it doesn't matter, because there is no user input or side effects

**UPDATE 2**

The problem was in data source. All code in question work correctly. Problem closed.

Comment: How do you use `SomeViewModel`? Please update your code to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code you've included looks fine, make sure you can reproduce it in a clean project and update to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right not it's missing `someSource`, `SomeViewModel` is not inherited from `ViewModel`, etc. I should be able to reproduce it by copy-pasting your code into my empty project to be able to help you

Comment: @PylypDukhov unfortinatly, i can't, because MRE will be very large and i have NDA

Comment: You're loosing the Minimal part. I'm not asking for a huge example. Try to reproduce it in as much small environment as possible. You can start in your real project by removing some parts which you think are not related. As I said your current code looks like it should work, so problem is probably in some other place.

Answer (score -1):

`object` wrapping is completely redundant (no fields, no functions), you can remove it (also, change the name so it won't confuse with compose's `State`):

```
data class MyState(
    val mainPhotos: List<S3Photo>? = emptyList(),
)
```

According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables), you need to **create** the state in the view model, and **observe** the state in the composable function - your code is a bit unclear for me so I'll just show you how I do it in my apps.

**create** the state in the view model:

```
class SomeViewModel() {
    private val viewState = mutableStateOf(MyState())

    // Expose as immutable so it won't be edited
    fun getState(): State<MyState> = viewState

    init {
        val photos = someSource.load()
        viewState.value = viewState.value.copy(mainPhotos = photos)
    }
}
```

**observe** the state in the composable function:

```
@Composable
fun SomeDistanation() {
    val viewModel: SomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val state: MyState by remember { viewModel.getState() }
    SomeViewFun(state)
}
```

Now you'll get automatic recomposition in case the state changes.

Comment: ```object SomeState``` hold 3 classes: State, Events and Effects, that is why wrapping isn't redurant. I have about 10 values in State class and only ```List<S3Photo>``` doesn't calls recompose. For ex state value like '''isLoading: Boolean = false``` works and starts progress indicator when changes

Comment: Tnx for the extra info :) and sorry for misunderstanding. Did you try it the way I offered? does it work?